# docker 1.11.2 on snappy cannot open /dev/bus

Tags: usb, permissions, ubuntu-core, docker

I have recently updated to

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$ snappy list
Name          Date       Version Developer 
ubuntu-core   2016-08-11 17      ubuntu    
curl          2016-06-02 0.1.10  tetor     
docker        2016-09-25 1.11.2  canonical 
generic-amd64 2016-01-20 1.4     canonical 
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$
```

and since then docker does not reach the USB devices anymore. (this used to work before the update)

```
docker run  --rm --net=host --privileged --name=abc -v /dev/urandom:/dev/random -v /dev/bus:/dev/bus -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/ubuntu/apk:/opt/abc/my-container bash
/apps/docker/1.11.2/bin/amd64/docker: Error response from daemon: linux runtime spec devices: open /dev/bus: permission denied.
```

I have already assigned whatever I could to docker:

```
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$ sudo snappy hw-info
docker: /dev/bus/usb/001/001, /dev/bus/usb/001/002, /dev/bus/usb/001/003, /dev/bus/usb/002/001, /dev/bus
(amd64)ubuntu@localhost:~$
```

I have even done a chmod -R 777 on /dev/bus but not even that helped.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh found it. I had to enable this:

```
sudo docker-privilege on
```